# Behringer C1-U Microphone Static Noise In Background

Tags: microphone, sound, noise, usb, behringer

So I got my Behringer C1-U Microphone for my birthday on the 19th of November, and the Microphone has been amazing since just recently, all of sudden there has been a super annoying static sound in the background of the Microphone, when I push down on the metal brace that the microphone has it does the sound A LOT louder, but if I hold the bottom of the microphone the sound gets kinda quieter, but I haven't been able to eliminate the sound entirely and it's really annoying me and giving my friends headaches when I use stuff that doesn't have a noise suppression built into it. Here's an example of the noise. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OrIX3cGfphOnOrMnEUODOcpVFbMl8COj and here's a picture of the actual Microphone https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T7ZtzwznZRgUk0Nm8nuRN-WG0qoQT2T2 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK that sound is mains frequency induction into the microphone or the cable. It can be eliminated by ensuring you have a correctly balanced cable between your interface and microphone. If, once checking you have correct cabling, you are still hearing this noise, then you possibly have a power supply or interface issue.